# Missing endmarks with ntheorem when ending with a formula

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
% proof
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theoremprework{\medbreak}
\theorempostwork{\medbreak}
\theoremindent0mm
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem*{beweis}{Beweis.}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{beweis}
    This is really just a formula
    \begin{equation*}
        a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation*}
\end{beweis}
\end{document}
```

Because the proof ends with a formula, I don't get the endmarks, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two items:

1. `ntheorem` does not hook into `amsmath` envs unless you tell it to, add the `amsmath` option to `ntheorem`
2. You `\Box` command is not defined by default, remember to add the `amssymb` package.